# SDCard content exist but cant see them

Tags: android, android-sdcard, galaxy

I am having very Strange problem with my Samsung Nexus with Android 4.0.2. I wrote a simple program which basically create file each time user presses a button. My program is working great on other devices where as on Galaxy Nexus Windows/Mac can not see those files on SD card, but when i do adb shell i see all files on SD Card.

I retest this on another Nexus which has Android 4.0.4 but still same result.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably need to index your files via `MediaScannerConnection`. Quoting myself [from a blog post from last year](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html):

> ...the MTP contents are not based on the literal contents of external storage. Instead, MTP contents are based on what files have been scanned by MediaScannerConnection. If you write a file to external storage, until and unless that file is scanned by MediaScannerConnection, it will not be visible to users over MTP.
>
> External storage is scanned on a reboot and possibly on a periodic basis. Users can manually force a scan via utilities like SDRescan. However, the best answer is for you to use scanFile() on MediaScannerConnection to update the media database after you close your file. This will make your file immediately available to the user.