# File created on sdcard but not accessible on PC

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SDCard content exist but cant see them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643476/sdcard-content-exist-but-cant-see-them)

I'm learning to develop apps on Android.

I managed to create and write to a file on sdcard. I can see this file and it's contents on my phone through File Manager, however, when I connect my phone to PC, I cannot see this file I just created.

Has anyone encountered this before? I can't seem to find a explanation for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDCard content exist but cant see them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643476/sdcard-content-exist-but-cant-see-them) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170214/image-saved-to-sdcard-doesnt-appear-in-androids-gallery-app and others