# File created from Android app is not visible until renamed

Tags: android, file

everybody!

I create a file in my android app with this code, run in UI thread:

```
final File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
final File file = new File(dir, "file" + System.currentTimeMillis()); //$NON-NLS-1$

try
{
   file.createNewFile())
}

catch (Exception e)
{
   ...
}
```

and I can't see it on my Win7 PC, until I rename the file on the phone with the file browser. I run the program on Samsung Galaxy Nexus, OS ver 4.0.2. What might be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: With an android 4.0.2 device you are probably running into the MTP / emulated external storage behavior, and probably have a file browser that knows to handle that - see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643476/sdcard-content-exist-but-cant-see-them

Comment: Why you are not giving any file extension

Comment: Thanks a lot for the post, Chris! Yes, MTP is used. I added `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(),
new String[] {path}, null, this);` but it didn't solve the problem. The callback gets called, and both params seem to be ok: `path = /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/<package>/files` and `uri = content://media/external/file/2014`. The file doesn't appear in Win Explorer until I somehow rename it, though. BTW, I added the ".txt" extension, but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

At last!

The solution is to use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {path}, null, null);`, but `path` must include THE NAME OF THE FILE, not only the path. No extension is necessary.

At least, it worked in my case :) .

Huge thanks to Chris Stratton.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found yet, is install SSHDroid on the device and WinSCP on Win7.